# Can we convert Result in ResultSet to Vertex by using gremlin - java client?

Tags: java, graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am using a Github example to generate a graph (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-java-getting-started). And now I want to query it and hold a vertex instance in my hand to traverse further depending on further inputs from the user in a knowledge graph.

Submitting this gremlin query:  `g.V().hasLabel('schedule').inE().outV().hasLabel('url').as('a').dedup()
.where(and(out().hasLabel('schedule').has('name','3'),out()
.hasLabel('states').has('name', 'federal'))).select('a')`

```
// Submitting remote query to the server.
ResultSet results = client.submit(query);

CompletableFuture<List<Result>> completableFutureResults = results.all();
List<Result> resultList = completableFutureResults.get();

for (Result result : resultList) {
    System.out.println("My vertex--"+result.getVertex());
    System.out.println("\nQuery result:");
    System.out.println("resultssssss-"+result.toString());
}
```

How can I do that as right now I am getting a class cast exception as mentioned below:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Result.getVertex(Result.java:131)
    at GetStarted.Dynamic.main(Dynamic.java:155)
```

Comment: Thanks .But this won't help , I want a gremlin query that can give me list of vertices at the end that I can convert it into tinkerpop vertex or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The `select('a')` seems redundant to me - I think that can be removed. It is selecting an output that is already the current output of `where()` which is already that vertex at "a" which means your traversal should be:

```
g.V().hasLabel('schedule').
  in().hasLabel('url').
  dedup().
  where(and(out().hasLabel('schedule').has('name','3'),
            out().hasLabel('states').has('name', 'federal')))
```

I guess a further optimization would be to do the `out()` before the `and()` so you only traverse those edges once:

```
g.V().hasLabel('schedule').
  in().hasLabel('url').
  dedup().
  where(out().and(has('schedule','name','3'),
                  has('states', 'name', 'federal')))
```

Now...that returns a `Vertex`, however, what you had should have also returned a `Vertex`. At least according to TinkerPop specifications, when doing a `select()` on a single label you should get back a single object. However, if you do multiple labels then you would get a `Map`. You can see this demonstrated with TinkerGraph here:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').as('a').out().as('b').select('a')
==>v[1]
==>v[1]
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').as('a').out().as('b').select('a','b')
==>[a:v[1],b:v[3]]
==>[a:v[1],b:v[2]]
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4]]
==>[a:v[4],b:v[5]]
==>[a:v[4],b:v[3]]
==>[a:v[6],b:v[3]]
```

It makes me wonder if CosmosDB has that little nuance covered properly - if not, then that's technically a "bug".